# Cannot ping ec2 instances in the same private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instances in the same private subnet. I am trying to ping the IP of one EC2 instance to the other instance but getting timeout issues.

Both instances are added to a security group. The rules of this security group are:

```
Inbound - All Traffic - All Traffic - <VPC CIDR>
Outbound- All Traffic - All Traffic - <VPC CIDR>
```

On the private subnet, there are net ACLs but these have inbound and outbound rules for:

```
All Traffic - All Traffic - <VPC CIDR>
```

I would have expected to be able to ping the each of the EC2 instances that are in the same private subnet given the rules that I added.

Is there some other rule that I am missing?

Do instances within the subnet require anything else to allow communication between the instances?

**Edit: Answer**
The Windows firewall rules on the machine were preventing pinging between the instances. This was disabled to confirm it was the case, with the necessary rules added later.

Comment: I would be tempted to reset the VPC to its default security groups, routes, and NACLs, add an SG for the 2 EC2 instances, allow inbound All ICMP from the SG to itself, and then verify ping works. Then start re-applying your customizations to find out which breaks it. NACL changes are always suspect (and rarely needed). This presumes the instances actually accept and respond to ICMP ping, of course, and do not have any onboard iptables rules that would block ICMP.

Comment: For testing I have added the instances in the private subnet to a SG with open in and outbound. I've reverted to default NACL.
Might I be missing something in the route table? I have local traffic and an internet gateway in there.

Comment: Assuming your VPC is 10/16, the route table should presumably be 10.0.0.0/16 local and 0.0.0.0/0 IGW. Also, see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-vpc-route-table/

Comment: Issue was the local firewall. I opened rules and it solved the problem.

Comment: Happy to provide that as the answer, given that it was proposed in my first comment earlier. Or you can answer yourself.

Comment: I wish I had a dollar for every time someone said “I can’t ping” and then later discovered a firewall. Smh.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow all **ICMP** traffic in your security group definition. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-ping
[image]

Comment: I couldn't find that exact rule so I added the following to the SG

All ICMP - IPv4 - All - n/a - <vpc cidr>

Still no pinging between both instances.